# Strange wrong colors in XP Mode under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, colors, windows-xp-mode, cms

I have a fresh install of XP Mode under my Windows 7 x64. I have a `0.png` image file with a uniform white background with RGB color equal to (240, 240, 240).

And I have strange inconsistent color measurements of this background (click on image to enlarge it):

[image]

- Opened directly in Paint under XP, it has proper color (240, 240, 240).
- Open it with default viewer under XP, take a screen shot, paste result to Paint. Now we have wrong color (247, 243, 247).
- Paste result to Irfan View. Color is again proper (240, 240, 240).
- Take screen shot of the window with XP Mode under host Win7 and check all colors. They are all wrong (247, 243, 247).

I thought this issue is related to color profiles, and I found that color management in XP is done via Display → Settings → Advanced, but this setting is not accessible:

[image]

It is a fresh install, I did not change *anything* in XP. I did not encounter this problem on my previous Windows 7 x64 install, so maybe something is wrong on the host side. But what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting 24-bit color quality using the method described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2011/10/10/enabling-24-bit-color-in-windows-xp-mode.aspx). Now proper color is displayed in all places.